# ASP.NET MVC 5 Entity Framework 6 bring data from different tables in Select expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, entity-framework-6

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application with Entity Framework 6.

I had imported the entities from the database. In particular, I have 2 entities
`Users` and `PortalPicture`. I need to bring user data with his picture, but, if picture column is null, I have to use a standard picture from `PortalPicture`.

I have a stored procedure that looks like this:

```
select 
    U.Name, U.LastName, U.Email, U.Password,
    isnull(U.Picture, (select Picture 
                       from PortalPicture with(nolock) 
                       where name = 'USER')) Picture
from 
    users U with(nolock)
where 
    User_id = @User_id
```

In Entity Framework, I get `User` data like this:

```
public Users GetById(long User_id)
{
    Users users = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.User_id == User_id);
    return users;
}
```

Is there a way to bring `PortalPicture` in the same expression n as it shows `Select` expression?

Thanks

Comment: Not without a foreign key between these tables. Entity Framework doesn't do sub queries. Although, you *could* simply use your existing stored procedure instead of getting your users through the `Users` `DbSet`.

Comment: Thanks, the idea is replace SP (Enterprise Library) whtn ORM (entity Framework)...

Comment: Some times the stored procedure way is better. Just because you're using an ORM, doesn't mean you need to use the ORM for *everything*.

Comment: I do not like ORM, i prefer to use SP all times, but it is not mi desicion. Thanks